# Note with hint for getting to the center of Sleet island?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock-2

I understand (from checking online) that there's a note (or some other kind of hint?) somewhere telling you how to get to the center island of the "Sleet island" location.
I've searched everywhere, but must have missed it - does anyone know where the note's located?

Note that I'm not asking how to get to the center of Sleet island (very easy to find via google) or what the note contains. If you wish to include this in the answer, please put it below the location of the note.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to divide this answer into a sequence of hints enclosed in spoiler tags, so you won't neccessarily be robbed of the joy of finding out yourself.

Hint #1

> In the Sleet Island area, there are two statues in the northern/north-eastern area. One is silent, the other tells you that the silent one has a friend to the east, who might be more talkative.

Hint #2

> What is this area to the east? The Cemetery! Inside, you will find another talking head refering to the silent one.

Hint #3

> This head says that the silent one sees something every night.

Hint #4 and the final one, with the solution.

> The solution is to go to the silent statue and rest until night. You should see a certain someone in the direction the statue is looking.

Comment: Thanks! (And thanks especially for dividing your answers into hints).